# HTML iFrame Screenshot Capture issue through JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, iframe, scorm, xapi

I am using [Html2Canvas](https://html2canvas.hertzen.com/documentation) JavaScript library to take screenshot of the content rendering in the iFrame.

The content in the iFrame is the Scorm/xAPI (src=folder/index.html) file that is loading from the same server so I am not getting any CORS issue. Scorm/xAPI file is just like Power Point slide(s) that is embedded into iFrame to play in the web page.

The issue is that when I take screenshot of the iFrame I can only capture partial images because the content has flash objects / java applets plugins. HTML2Canvas library has some limitations and does not cater Flash Objects / Java Applets Plugins.

```
<button id="btn-screenshot">Button To Take Screenshot</button>
<iframe id="iframe" src="folder/index.html"></iframe>
<img src="" id="result" />
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {

        $(document).on('click', '#btn-screenshot', function () {
            let iframe = document.querySelector("#iframe").contentWindow.document.body;
            html2canvas(iframe).then(canvas => {
                let base64Canvas = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
                $('#result').attr('src',base64Canvas)
            });
        })

    })
</script>
```

This is the iFrame Content
[image]

This is the result of the screenshot
[image]

Comment: I think you are SOL

Comment: Hey @Hasan did you got the solution for this please let me know, because I have same issues

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same issue, all I have to do is **Replace all the relative path of the images, css and js file** then it works fine. I have statically changed relative path of those file from `<link href="mobile/player.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />` **to** `<link href="http://my-project.com/lms-365/mobile/player.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />`.
If you have access to the scorm files then you can do that, if not then you have use **regEx** for that.
**You may try something like this : **

```
$html=`
<img src="/relative/url/img.jpg" />
<form action="/">
<a href='/relative/url/'>Note the Single Quote</a>
<img src="//site.com/protocol-relative-img.jpg" />
`;

$base='https://example.com';

echo preg_replace('~(?:src|action|href)=[\'"]\K/(?!/)[^\'"]*~',"$base$0",$html);
```

**Output is :**

```
<img src="https://example.com/relative/url/img.jpg" />
<form action="https://example.com/">
<a href='https://example.com/relative/url/'>Note the Single Quote</a>
<img src="//site.com/protocol-relative-img.jpg" />
```

#### OR.....

You can use base element for this.

The `<base>` is an empty element that goes in the `<head>`. Using `<base href="https://example.com/path/" />` will tell all relative URLs in the document to refer to `https://example.com/path/` instead of the parent URL.
[Reference for base](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/base)